# Formatting date in HTML side with angular 2

Tags: html, angular

Need  to get  formatted  date. But  following  code  is  not  working ,  both  date  and  time  are  viewed. (need only  to  view  the  date part)

```
 <div class="form-group">               
       <input formControlName="startDate" type="date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" class="form-control" >
 </div>
```

when type  is assigned  as type="date", it does  not  bind  with the  value  we patched (set) .

Comment: you need to remove the other type property, you have two type property at the input element, try to remove the last one which is text.

Comment: It is  not  working  without  that  as well  .. Mistakenly  I have  added it to the  post

Comment: You need to write some code on input changes

Comment: <input formControlName="startDate" type="date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" class="form-control" #date value="{{ date.value | date }}">, you can use the pipes and set it in the value of the input

Comment: The `type` of an `input` is only to instruct the browser what type of data it should expect. In case of the mobile browsers, this will change the keyboard setting to either numeric values or enable the `web address` version of your keyboard. It doesn't do anything with parsing or checking data, there's different methods to do so both in Angular and in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my working Plunker links for both Reactive as well as Template Driven forms

[Reactive](https://plnkr.co/edit/AqWXJGEqOY93rqhxVLHh?p=preview) & [Template](https://plnkr.co/edit/8JKEEYIhpADMnUqpImhG?p=preview)

**For Reactive**

```
 <div class="form-group" formGroupName="address">
      <label for="">Date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="date">
    </div>
```

**For Template Driven**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-control="date" placeholder="date" required>
  </div>
```